# Android 4.4 - 8.1 location mode changes after device reboot

Tags: android

last week on tuesday 1/12/2021 all devices with version prior 9 started to set location mode to "Device only" after a device reboot.

This behavior changed suddenly, i didn't found anything about it. I have an app that requires high accuracy mode to work "fine" and this is affecting the normal usage of the app.

I wanted to know if there is an alternative to persist the high accuracy mode between reboots, and if this was intentionally changed by Google.

Thank you very much,
Jesús

Answer (score 0):

do you have more info?

I have 2 tablets
A Samsung Tab Galaxy 2 (T319) with Android 7 doesn't have this issue.
A Samsung Tab A6 (T585) with Android 8.1 with this issus since last week.

Comment: No but the issue was solved yesterday on 2 phones i have (Samsung J1 Ace, Huawei P8 lite). A friend of mine has a phone with Android 8 and the problem persists.